# CakePHP get full timestamp from PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, cakephp, timestamp

I am converting a CakePHP application from MySQL to PostgreSQL. Previously, I could get timestamp values using the CakePHP ORM and then run `strtotime` to get a unix timestamp.

It's not working with PostgreSQL right now because when I try using CakePHP's `find` to fetch records, timestamps are coming out like `2013-07-16 16:33 PM`.

I need a parseable timestamp with seconds precision. Is there somewhere in the cake libs where I can change this behavior globally?

Timestamp column type is `timestamptz`, and I'm just using the normal cakephp ORM to fetch the value. I'm running PostgreSQL 8.4.17 and CakePHP 2.3.5.

Comment: @AD7six I'm using PostgreSQL...

Comment: Timestamps were working fine in MySQL, but not in Postgres. I'll clarify the question.

Comment: What data type does the ORM return for the date of interest? (Hmm, actually, amazingly it looks like PHP doesn't have native date or timestamp data types)

Comment: @AD7six maybe it wasn't clear, but my example is in the question. "2013-07-16 16:33 PM" is an example of what I'm getting from CakePHP.

Comment: No its not clear - _show_ the code used that includes that string, the full result, the query from the query log - and the result of that query directly on the db. I.e. demonstrate that it _is_ php logic somewhere and not the db config.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it's working just fine at the database level.

If you want a particular output format for the timestamp in PostgreSQL, use the `to_char` function to format it as `text` for output, or use the client side application to format a native date to how you want it. If you want a unix timestamp, use `extract(epoch from date_column)`.

There's no way to set a custom timestamp format in PostgreSQL, you can only [choose from the ISO timestamp format or a few others](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-OUTPUT). It doesn't sound like that's the layer you're having issues with anyway, since you're not getting one of the supported formats, so I'd say your issues are at the ORM layer.

Maybe you need the [CakeTime function](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/time.html)?

Comment: Yes, I'm fairly certain that the problem is somewhere in CakePHP, but I can't find where to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `strtotime` on your dates to get them as timestamps?

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: 1) I'm not getting seconds in the timestamp, but I need seconds. 2) strtotime breaks when parsing datetime strings that contain both 24hour time and PM.

Comment: How is the date stored in the database? What's the datatype for the field and can you give some examples of records stored?

Comment: my examples are in the question.

Comment: I meant the examples of dates _in the database_, not that Cake is outputting.